# How to easily send local file to Google Cloud Storage in Scala

Tags: java, scala, storage, google-cloud-storage

I need to upload a local file to Google Cloud Storage using Scala language. What is the easiest way to do it? This file will also need to be public downloaded later.

Answer (score 2):

Use [the java library](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/apis/storage/v1) provided by Google. It will work with scala as well.

They provide an example of how to use this library [here](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/source/browse/storage-cmdline-sample/src/main/java/com/google/api/services/samples/storage/cmdline/StorageSample.java?repo=samples). It's in java but the scala equivalent should be easy to code.

Comment: The example provided uses Oauth2. I wanted a code that is independent from having a browser (it will run only in the server)

Comment: You will have to use oauth2 in any case. Just create a service account for your application. Check the google oauth library to know how to use a service account in your code. Your service account will have an email identifier, you must add this email to the bucket's permissions.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid it seems that the only way is to use the java client library. Please check here for more information:

[1] https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.cloud/google-cloud-storage

[2] https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/reference/libraries#client-libraries-install-java

A basic code would include the following libraries:

```
import com.google.cloud.storage.Storage.BlobListOption
import com.google.cloud.storage.{Blob, Bucket, StorageOptions}
import collection.JavaConverters._
```

where `JavaConverters` enables the conversion `Java <-> Scala` enabling the methods `.toScala` and `.toJava`.

Then, you need to instantiate the client with

```
val storage = StorageOptions.getDefaultInstance.getService
```

You also need to include in `build.sbt`:

```
libraryDependencies += "com.google.cloud" % "google-cloud-storage" % "1.113.15"
```

or using `spark-shell` this would be

```
spark-shell --packages "com.google.cloud:google-cloud-storage:1.113.15"
```