# Save a comma delimited string line by line as a named .txt file into Google Storage Bucket

Tags: scala, file-io, google-cloud-storage

I have a comma delimited string in Scala, and I want to first split the string by comma, so each word is in one line, and save this file in Google Storage Bucket. I can only save the whole string as it is (so not breaking by comma to different lines) and I cannot rename the file in Google Storage Bucket. Can you help? Here is my code.

```
val x = "a,b,c,d"
sc.parallelize(sc.parallelize(List(x)).collect()).coalesce(1).saveAsTextFile("gs://myReport/Output_x")
```

This piece of script saves the string into a flat file automatically called `part-00000`, so no suffix. And all the contents are in the same line. So I have it like this:

```
a,b,c,d
```

What I want is a file called `table1.txt` saved in the same place of the Google Bucket. And the contents should be like this:

```
a
b
c
d
```

Can Scala do it?

Comment: `x.replaceAll(",","\n")`

Comment: Thank you @jwvh Your suggestion solved half of the question, which is exciting. now the file content is listed by lines rather than one line with comma. Do you know how to save it in Google Bucket with a desired name?

Comment: You can't save a file directly as you would in a local directory, you have to first create it in memory and then use the Cloud Storage SDK to do it, you can see in this [community post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25540158/how-to-easily-send-local-file-to-google-cloud-storage-in-scala) how you can upload it in Scala. Let me know if this fixes your issue.

Comment: Thank you @ralemos Do you mean that I need to save it in local first, and then upload to the google bucket? Not sure I find an example in the link you provided. Could you be more specific?

Comment: Yes, either save it locally or create the file in memory, I never used scala so I am not sure how you can do it but if you use [this library](https://index.scala-lang.org/tkrs/gcs-scala/gcs-scala-core/0.3.1?target=_2.12) which is based on the java library for GCS, you will be able to do it, here is the [Java Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/uploading-objects#storage-upload-object-code-sample) which have some examples.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by @Jwvh, you can use `x.replaceAll(",","\n")` to replace the commas in your file by a line break.

For the second part of your question however, you can't save a file directly as you would in a local directory, you have to either save it locally or create the file in memory and only then use the Cloud Storage SDK to upload it to Cloud Storage, in order to do that you can use this [GCS library for Scala](https://index.scala-lang.org/tkrs/gcs-scala/gcs-scala-core/0.3.1?target=_2.12).